# 1>MDAVSCLI : error : EPERM, operation not permitted 'C:\Windows\CSC\v2.0.6'

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, visual-studio-cordova

I recently installed VS tools for Cordova on VS2013 with a successful install of all default settings.  Upon trying to build and run the default "BlankCordovaApp" template, I get a node error.

> 1>MDAVSCLI : error : EPERM, operation not permitted
>   'C:\Windows\CSC\v2.0.6'

According to other SO posts, the directory it references is tied to offline sync, of which I have since turned off and restarted the machine with no success.

I've searched and found similar issues, but none that deal with this directory and none that have resolved the issue.

The full build output is below:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp1, Configuration: Debug Windows Phone 8 ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(95,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  GeneratedJavascript=
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(208,5): error : '\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(208,5): error : CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(208,5): error : UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
1>  C:\Windows>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\QUH3Q3IS.ARB\packages\vs-mda
1>MDAVSCLI : error : EPERM, operation not permitted 'C:\Windows\CSC\v2.0.6'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro in a VM (VMWare Fusion 7) with all the latest updates from VS and Windows Update, etc. and kept everything as vanilla as possible to get started.

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 3):

I dug a little deeper and ran the diagnostic build from Visual Studio (Tools>Options>Projects and Solutions>Build and Run>Set MSBuild project build output verbosity= Diagnostic), and saw more details about a UNC path error that was thrown, which was also shown in my original output.  Turns out you can't build with a UNC path.

I moved my project to a local folder (C:\Projects...) and that allowed it to build just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found was moving the project to C:\MyProject and then start Visual Studio as administrator and it works properly